# Resizing Partial dependency plots - looks too small

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I have created partial dependency plots via Scikit learn's library. However, I'm facing a challenge in resizing the plots to be much bigger as I could read all the plots entirely. Is there a method available to change plot view and size ?

Code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble.partial_dependence import partial_dependence, plot_partial_dependence
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
import numpy as np

my_model = GradientBoostingRegressor()
my_model.fit(X, y)

my_plots = plot_partial_dependence(my_model,       
                        features=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22],
                        X=X,        
                        feature_names=['core_self_evaluations', '1b_score', 'investigate','respect_for_people','social','mastery_orientation','realistic','conventional','astronaut_score','innovation','agreeableness','gradeClass_second_lower','AC_TeamPlayer','enterprising','AC_Problemsolving','AC_StartsConversation','verbal','leadership_score','Race_chinese','performance_orientation','self_monitoring','UniLoc_overseas','attention_to_detail'], # labels on graphs
                        grid_resolution=5)
```

Plot created:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solved the sizing problem with the below code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plot_partial_dependence(my_model,       
                        features=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22],
                        X=X,        
                        feature_names=['core_self_evaluations', '1b_score', 'investigate','respect_for_people','social','mastery_orientation','realistic','conventional','astronaut_score','innovation','agreeableness','gradeClass_second_lower','AC_TeamPlayer','enterprising','AC_Problemsolving','AC_StartsConversation','verbal','leadership_score','Race_chinese','performance_orientation','self_monitoring','UniLoc_overseas','attention_to_detail'], # labels on graphs
                        grid_resolution=5) 
fig.set_figwidth(8)
fig.set_figheight(15)
fig.tight_layout()
```

This provides really good layout with customisable height and width. The hint to look at is the return value of the method (which is "fig" and "ax"). Using these two return values, extra options become available such as setting the width and height, independently.

Comment: Dear Dinesh, since most of your covariates return constant horizontal lines in the Partial dependency plots, should'nt you be dropping them off from your analysis? It would also help better depict the main features of your model.

Comment: Dear Philipe, sorry for my late response. Yes, you're right. I've lost track of my original data of my analysis. But your suggestions are correct.

Answer (score 5):

The `ax` param is new in v 0.22.

Here's the current way:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 14))
plot_partial_dependence(est, X, ax=ax)
```

Updated [examples](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_partial_dependence_visualization_api.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-miscellaneous-plot-partial-dependence-visualization-api-py) for the current API.